# El filtro de datatable no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

**la búsqueda de datatable no me hace el filtro creo que el tbody es el problema pero requiero del ID para traer los datos de firebase.
En el archivo html el tdoby tiene un ID que es tabla**

```
var db = firebase.firestore();


$(document).ready( function () {
     $('#table_id').DataTable({
      language: {
        search: "Buscar:",
       
    }
    });
  } );
```

**el siguiente código lo tengo en un archivo js**

```
  var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
  db.collection("usuarios dashboard").onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=> {
    tabla.innerHTML= ``; 
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
     console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()} `);
     tabla.innerHTML += `
     <tr>
     <th>${doc.id}</th>
     <td>${doc.data().nombre}</td>
     <td>${doc.data().apellido}</td>
     <td>${doc.data().telefono}</td>
     <td>${doc.data().edad}</td>
     <td>${doc.data().cedula}</td>
     </tr>
   `;
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es el que tengo en html

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-dordered " style="width:90%" >
  <thead class="thead-dark texte-center">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Telefono</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
      <th>Cedula</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
 
  <tbody id="tabla">
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```